# Samsung Galaxy A3 - stuck on empty battery boot screen after total battery drain

Tags: charging, boot, system-freeze, samsung-galaxy-a3

So, the battery on my Samsung Galaxy A3 drained completely. Then I plugged in USB cable, and the empty battery logo appeared - and nothing else, to graphics to indicate it was charging:

[image: phone-stuck-boot-empty battery]

I left the USB plugged in for some 15-20 minutes, then I unplugged it.

Now the screen STILL shows an empty battery logo, even after some 15-20 minutes after unplugging.

I had kept power button pressed for more than 30 seconds, nothing happens.

I had kept Volume Up + Power button pressed for more than 10 seconds, in hopes it would reboot to recovery, nothing happens.

I would have taken out the battery at this point, but this damn phone does not allow the battery to be replaced.

What do I do now to get this phone working again?

Answer (score 0):

Found here: [Fastboot Mode SAMSUNG Galaxy A3 Core - HardReset.info https://www.hardreset.info › devices](https://www.hardreset.info/devices/samsung/samsung-galaxy-a3-core/fastboot-mode/)

> hold down Volume Down and Power button to turn off the smartphone

That is what I did: help Volume Down and Power button pressed together for about 10 seconds, and the phone turned off (the empty battery icon disappeared), and then it rebooted normally to system - I quickly plugged in the USB cable when I noticed it was rebooting to system, and now it is charging. Phewwwwwwww.....

Comment: Interesting, what is "Volume Down and Power button pressed together" supposed to do? It didn't help with the problem I have here https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/252095/samsung-j5-stuck-in-boot-up-switch-off-cycle