# Samsung J5 stuck in boot-up/switch-off cycle

Tags: samsung, boot

My Samsung J5, 2017 appears stuck and I'd like to learn whether there is an appropriate button-press sequence.  **(EDIT #2)**

**EDIT Latest 28th June 2023**

I bought and tried a new battery. Unfortunately when I tried a normal switch on it went straight into the same boot cycle.

I took the new battery out, left it couple of days and then put it back and tried just plugging in a usb cable from a pc and for the first time it briefly showed an empty grey battery symbol and then the screen went black. As this is a radically different response I'm hoping it is actually charging and that this might make a difference. I will post an update when there is news.

**End of edit**

**History:**

A couple of days ago I noticed the phone had powered off. I plugged in a charger and moments later pressed the power button. Sometimes that had worked in the past, sometimes it would sit with a flat battery graphic for twenty minutes before allowing itself to be booted up.  This time, instead of either of those outcomes it began the boot sequence, Samsung logo appeared and then the screen went off, then it buzzed and the cycle began again, repeating every 10 to 30 seconds.

**I have tried:**

1. unplugging it and waiting, then trying again (it mostly stops the cycling with the charger unplugged and I presume the battery is still flat)
2. unplugging it, pressing the power button (as I thought that would force a power off)
3. unplugging it, removing the battery, re-assembly (in this case the endless cycle didn't start again when I put the battery in and pressed the power button, I think it only started again when I plugged the charger back in)
4. a different charger
5. an older battery
   None of these changed the basic pattern.

Then I looked up button press sequences, just guessing there might be something. What I've found is countless forums referring to things such as Recovery Mode, Safe mode, Download Mode, Boot loader, this and that etc though with very sketchy descriptions of what these are about or where to find out more.

I then tried:

6. plugging in after battery replaced, then immediately simultaneously pressing the power button, home button and volume-down button - then releasing the power button when the Samsung logo appeared on the first cycle. This resulted in the screen changing to the attached image #1 below (though it wasn't connected to a PC so I don't have any understanding of why it came up with the "Downloading" title):
   [image: Image #1]
7. as 6 but simultaneously pressing the up-volume and power button. This resulted in the attached image #2 below:
   [image: Image #2]

**Other observations (EDIT #2)**

1. I've noticed now that sometimes it can get into the boot/crash cycle without a charger plugged in. i.e. there is enough juice remaining to have another go at the end of each cycle. I haven't tried leaving it indefinitely like that as it doesn't feel like it is doing it any good.
2. I'm less confident now that I know which of those two sequences led to which screenshot - I'm wondering if it depends when in the boot/logoscreen/switch-off cycle that I start the button press sequence.

**Provisional Conclusion (EDIT #1 still relevant at EDIT #2)**
The very fact that both of these two button press sequences, items 6 and 7, got the phone out of its infinite loop means, to me, that there must be further mileage here, even if I don't know how to make use of these sequences yet.

**At last, the question:**

Amongst the various modes such as Recovery Mode, Safe mode, Download Mode etc,

a)  what might be the right mode for this problem?

b)  falling short of an answer for a) what might at least be a sensible first try - i.e. which sequence makes most sense?

c)  what do I do once I've actually got into whatever mode it is? (short of doing anything that will scrub data and photos from apps recorded however that is done [there is no separate SD card fitted])

Comment: Based on your description my first guess was a dead battery, but usually in such a case a connected charger should change the behavior. So may be in your case the battery is just empty but the phone doesn't manage to charge it and booting requires too much power so it crashes and restarts. Do you see a possibility to charge one of the batteries externally and then use it in your phone?

Comment: @Robert Thanks, I wouldn't exclude that if nothing else works though the battery wasn't in bad shape beforehand, i.e. it still had a fair bit of capacity, I didn't make a habit of running it completely flat but on the occasions that had previously happened it had subsequently started ok. I am assuming that it got into this mess by me pressing start too soon after plugging in the charger. I have edited the question to emphasize where I want to go with this.

Comment: On aged batteries the capacity is often not the problem. More problems is causing that the battery can no longer provide enough power in a short time, e.g. if the CPU is busy. In such cases the provided current is not enough and then the voltage drops and the system crashes.

Comment: @Robert fair point. What do you make of the fact that some button press sequences do result in it stepping out of that crash sequence?  Surely this means there is potential to use a Recovery/Safe/etc mode to exit the crash loop. I've noticed now that sometimes it can get into the boot/crash cycle without a charger plugged in. Does that not mean that there is enough juice remaining to have another go at the end of each cycle and that there is mileage in knowing how to apply the Recovery/Safe modes etc. I've updated the question with this new observation.